# How do I nest a For Loop w/ IF statement to return a new list?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, typeerror, nameerror

Can the return in an If statement append a list?

Is python aware that the list elements are actually dictionaries and that 'sublist' iterates over those elements?

**I tried being data type specific after For previously and that doesn't help**

Is the If statement actually accessing the dictionary?

My code:

```
In[1]: restaurants = [fork_fig, frontier_restaurant]
In [2]: def open_restaurants(restaurants):
    for sublsit in restaurants:
        op=[]
        if sublist.get('is_closed')==False:
            op.append(sublist.get('name'))
```

passed through their code:

```
In [1]: len(open_restaurants(restaurants))

Out[2]: NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-14-e78afc732a29> in <module>
    ----> 1 len(open_restaurants(restaurants)) # 1

    <ipython-input-13-56ad484d6dd9> in open_restaurants(restaurants)
          2     for sublsit in restaurants:
          3         op=[]
    ----> 4         if sublist.get('is_closed')==False:
          5             op.append(sublist.get('name'))
          6 

    NameError: name 'sublist' is not defined
```

and next: I think this is because the list i defined is not populating with the correct information.

```
In[3]: open_restaurants(restaurants)[0]['name'] # 'Fork & Fig'

Out[4]:TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bf5607d088f4> in <module>
----> 1 open_restaurants(restaurants)[0]['name'] # 'Fork & Fig'

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your indentation may be not correct
2. You didn't return the result (probably `return op`) in your function

Comment: what can the return statement look like in an if statement? is python aware that the list elements are actually dictionaries and that sublist iterates over those elements? sorry for being dumb

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I was entering too much information.

The code that ended up working perfectly was as follows:

```
def open_restaurants(restaurants):
    op=[]
    for sublist in restaurants:
        if sublist['is_closed']==False:
            op.append(sublist)
        return op
```

1. I separated op list from the for loop.
2. Previously, the NameError said sublist was not defined, yet it was
   defined by including it in the `For`; to fix I removed `.get()` and
   replaced it with list form `x[]`.
3. Last, separated return from the `.append()` function.